# Wordpress: How to assign an extensiona s a homepage

Tags: wordpress

I am new user of wordpress. I downloaded and installed ShowDown "pictures battle" extension.

I would like to set it as default homepage.

I search during one hour in google, but I can't find the solution.

Someone can help me please to make this plugin my default homepage in wordpress?

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

You can set default WordPress homepage **Settings>Reading>Front page displays** and choose your desire page as home page

```
yourdomainmane/wp-admin/options-reading.php
```

[image]
[image]